# Need hint with MySQL query from 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need a small hint... I've got 2 Tables.
Table 1 gets data from an external api.
Table 2 is static.

Table 1: data

```
id name status ratio import_id
1  Test online  3     1
2  Tee  online  2     1
3  Test online  1     2
4  Tee  online  0.01  2
5  Test offline 4     3
6  Teee online  3     3
7  Teet online  1     3
```

Table 2: names

```
id name tag active
1  Test t1  1
2  Tee  t2  1
3  Teee t3  0
4  Teet t4  1
```

I want to have the ID from the table names (to write into another table and execute a cronjob)

Explanation Table 1:
id - AI
name - just the name
status - if the entry is active
ratio - the main select
import_id - every 10 minutes I do import from json (~40 entries)

what i've got:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT 
  import_id 
FROM 
  data 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

while($raw = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$the_id =  $raw->import_id;
echo $the_id;
}
```

Now I've got the ID and try to get the latest entry (import_id) with the highest ratio:

```
$c_result = mysql_query("
SELECT
  name, active, ratio, import_id 
FROM 
  data 
WHERE 
  active = '1' AND import_id = '$the_id' 
ORDER BY 
  ratio DESC LIMIT 1");

while($chosen = mysql_fetch_object($c_result))
{
$the_c = $chosen->name;
echo $the_c;
}
```

That works flawless. 
But it is possible that one of the 40 entries provided by api is not in my table "names" or it is not marked as "active".

But I only want the names.id of

- the name with the highest ratio
- which is in my table "names"
- which is marked as active in "names"
- and the data.status is online
- which is from the latest import (highest import_id)

and write it to another table.

I thought about a LEFT JOIN but if the names.name is not in the table "names" i just get an empty result.

Have you got a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Little confusing, How come your second query working? you don't have active in your `data` table.

Comment: Highest `id` or highest `import_id`? Your first query uses the highest `id`, but your list of criteria says highest `import_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d.name, active, ratio, import_id 
FROM data d
JOIN names n ON d.name = n.name
WHERE import_id = (SELECT import_id
                   FROM data
                   ORDER BY id DESC
                   LIMIT 1)
AND d.status = 'online'
AND n.active = 1
ORDER BY ratio DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98645/2)